# Почему в этом БСП нужно ставить тире, а не запятую?

Tags: запятые, тире, бсп

В то время люди не бездействовали — они успели связаться с главами  районных администраций.

Почему в этом БСП нужно ставить тире, а не запятую ?

Comment: Пожалуй, поддержу Ваш вопрос, Александр. Ответы, конечно, тоже.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Замечания к ответу  (для улучшения качества работы форума)**

Ответ верный (выбор тире), но есть замечания по качеству ответа.

***В то время люди не бездействовали — они успели связаться с главами районных администраций.***

1. Здесь **нет причинно-следственных отношений**, отношения между частями БСП **пояснительные.** Смысл в том, что раскрыто содержание, названное в первой части:  они не бездействовали,  а сделали следующее: связались с руководством.
2. Здесь действительно  нет перечисления и однородных отношений, но **запятой** обозначаются и **неоднородные отношения** тоже.
3. Теоретически в таких случаях можно поставить **один из трех знаков:** присоединительную запятую, присоединительное тире, двоеточие. Они заменяют друг друга,  так как интонация во всех случаях сходная – нисходяще-нисходящая. А отличаются варианты длительностью пауз: обозначенная пауза, подчеркнутая пауза, особо подчеркнутая пауза.
4. Но это **общее решение**, а задача решена, если выбор знака сделан. **Тире – это лучший вариант,** так как пояснительные отношения в этом БСП дополнены противопоставлением: не бездействовали, а действовали.
5. Сравнить: В то время люди не бездействовали, они успели связаться с главами районных администраций.   Здесь поставлена **присоединительная запятая,** она **допускается**, но обозначает только неоднородность отношений, а взаимообусловленность не  будет обозначена  должным образом.
6. **Двоеточие нежелательно,** хотя именно оно обычно ставится при пояснении. Но в данном случае пояснение можно обозначить тире, так как нет значительного  распространения темы, характерного для двоеточия.

Answer (score 2):

```
   Почему в этом БСП нужно ставить тире, а не запятую ?
```

Потому что запятая ставится при перечислении частей, похожих  по смыслу: Бледные щёки впали, глаза сделались большие, губы горели. Обычно в таких частях перечисляются события, происходящие одновременно или последовательно, а в данном предложении явные причинно - следственные связи.

*В то время люди не бездействовали — они успели связаться с главами районных администраций.* Не бездействовали (искали пути связи) и, как следствие, успели связаться.

Возможно и двоеточие: *В то время люди не бездействовали (что именно делали? какие действия производили?): они успели связаться с главами районных администраций.*